# Displaying custom media inline in facebook

Tags: facebook, youtube

When someone shares a YouTube video link on Facebook, Facebook renders youtube in the page itself, so that if user's want, they can watch it without going to YouTube page.

Are there any protocols which i can follow to allow Facebook to render my custom player (its more than just a video player) inline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to security concerns, Facebook will not allow anyone to have a custom player embedded.  Looks like the big dogs in the video industry (YouTube and Vimeo and more?) have struck deals with Facebook to allow their player to be embeddable within the feed display.  It probably cost lots of money to get that ability.  You should have your company contact Facebook to see if an agreement can be reached.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the times have changed. 
You can embed/inline any flash file you want.

Have a look at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/#audiovideo and http://developers.facebook.com/docs/share/ under Rich Media Sharing. You can use the Debugger (http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) to see if Facebook correctly gets you og-tags.